# How to draw a line with finger and detect if it's the area ? as3

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I've got an image on my AIR app where the user have to draw a line with his finger on it.
The purpose is to draw the line somewhere quite precise.

So, to draw a line, here's what I did :

```
var drawingLine:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChildAt(drawingLine,0);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, MouseDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);

function MouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void{
drawingLine.graphics.lineStyle(3);
drawingLine.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseMove);
}

function MouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void{
drawingLine.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
}

function MouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void{
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseMove);
}
```

So, now, how can I determine an area and check if the user has draw his lines in the area ?

I thought about using `hitTestObject` but I don't think that's the good way to do it.

Comment: `hitTestObject` seems fine since that its purpose. How is it not working for you? Maybe we can help... PS: `var drawingLine:Sprite = new Sprite();` might be lighter since you want a container not a timeline.

Comment: Should the line be inside that area completely? Or does it suffice if it merely touches the area? Can the line be partially outside of the area?

Comment: The line should be inside the area completely. If possible, of course.

Comment: Any idea how can use `hitTestObject` in this context @VC.One ? Something like : `if (drawingLine.hitTestObject(area1)) { trace("good");`